# google-places dropdown select not working sometime in safari

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, google-places

In mobile safari browser, sometimes when i click on goggle places options dropdown that doesn't work. So basically i select and the dropdwon closes but nothing appears in input.

I tried this solution also :

```
     $timeout(function () {
                        var container =  document.getElementsByClassName('pac-container');
                       // disable ionic data tab
                           angular.element(container).attr('data-tap-disabled', 'true');
                      // leave input field if google-address-entry is selected
                        angular.element(container).on("click", function(){
                         document.getElementById('autocomplete').blur();
                            });

                    }, 500);
                }
            }
```

But it doesn't work. Sometimes the selection works fine but not all time